# How to count the occurence of each text value in a column of a data frame and then remove the duplicate rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

Can anyone tell me how I can count the number of time each Author id occurs in the Author.id column using a simple code? I also want to remove duplicate Author.id after the calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)
scopus<-read.csv("scopus.csv")
scopus_selected<-scopus%>%
  select(Author.ID,Citing.literature)%>%
  group_by(Author.ID)%>%
  mutate(citations=sum(Citing.literature))
```

My data frame is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Use `dplyr::count(mydf, myvar)` to count the number of occurrences, and `dplyr::distinct(mydf, myvar, .keep_all = TRUE)` to remove dupes. Note that only the first occurrence will be kept.

Comment: I've tried it myself as well. I've actually used: select(Author.ID,Citing.literature) %>% group_by(Author.ID) %>% summarize(publications=n( ),citations=sum(Citing.literature)) %>% na.omit( ).  This code worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
scopus %>% 
    group_by(Author.ID) %>% 
    summarize(citations = sum(Citing.literature), 
              num_occurrences = n())
```